# Reference for a theorem of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I saw a theorem in a Russian book, and the theorem says something like this,

If the function $F(x,y,y')=0$ is $C^1$ (continuos partial derivatives with respect to $y$ and $y'$), then the solution of $\dfrac{\partial F(x,y,y')}{\partial y'}=0$ is a particular solution of $F(x,y,y')=0$

Whats the matter is that, the book is in Russian and it is so tediously to use the translator, and the book is in fact a collection of problems so it does'n say too much about theory.

If you can recommend some bibliography in which i can find theory about the theorem, it will be so useful.

Comment: Would a proof help?  That I might have . . .

Comment: Yeah, sure. I would like to know under what conditions the theorem is true.